# Accessing the nginx.config file on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I have recently migrated a PHP application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The application is using nginx as the server.

However, in order to get the application running properly, I need to edit the nginx.config file. I cannot find a way to access this. The documentation I have looked at suggests that this might be possible by adding a file to the .ebextensions folder when deploying the build. However, I do not know what type of file / syntax I would need to write this or how to get this to update the nginx.config file. Moreover, I cannot tell whether such an additional file might overwrite the default configuration file and cause more problems.

My questions are then:

1. Is it possible to access and edit the nginx.config file directly? This would be the preferred solution, as I know how to edit an nginx configuration file.
2. If not, how does one add specific configuration options for nginx to a file in the .ebextensions folder?
3. Going this way, does one have to specify the entire nginx configuration file or is it possible to just add options? In particular, I wish to add a 'locations' term, so that unknown URLs are redirected to the index.php page.

I would greatly appreciate any advice from any one with experience in this area.